# Can't extract data from list of dictionaries, 'NoneType' object is not subscript

Tags: python, pickle

I have a pickle file `AQM_kath.pkl` that is two sensor locations and their data in a dictionary.

```
len(AQM_kath)
>>> 2

len(AQM_kath[0])
>>> 1011

len(AQM_kath[1])
>>> 1026
```

Each of the entries in the respective lists is a dictionary entry (sensor 1 has 1011 entries, sensor 2 has 1026) with several keys. I am trying to run through both sensor locations (AQM_kath[0] and AQM_kath[1]) and compile all of the data entries of a specific key into 1 list. The included keys are `Image`, `Date`, `Time`, and `Temp`. Here is what i have tried so far for temperature, my end goal is a 2037 length list of temperatures:

```
import pickle as pkl
import numpy as np

temp =[]
with open('/work/AQM_kath.pkl', 'rb') as fp:
    for station in tqdm(pkl.load(fp)):
        for data_point in station:
            temp.append(data_point['Temp'])
```

However i get the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-41f4e4b6f854> in <module>
      3     for station in tqdm(pkl.load(fp), position=0, leave=True):
      4         for data_point in station:
----> 5             temp.append(data_point['Temp'])

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

It works for the first 10 entries, but then spits out this error. Not sure what i'm missing here, any help appreciated!

Comment: Apparently, one of the elements is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> Each of the entries in the respective lists is a dictionary entry

but this is apparently wrong. There are also some `None` entries mixed into the lists. Assuming this is normal, you can skip them.

```
with open('/work/AQM_kath.pkl', 'rb') as fp:
    for station in tqdm(pkl.load(fp)):
        for data_point in station:
            if data_point:
                temp.append(data_point['Temp'])
```

If this is not expected, you should figure out why incomplete data is being written to the file in the first place and fix that.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am unsure how to go about filtering my data so that there are no `None` values, but that is something I can work on later. Thank you!